# Need help to spot null pointer exception java

Tags: java, android, exception, null, point

When i compile this to my android device it gives me a null pointer exception. i have been trying to find where the null pointer exception is, but without any luck. i have an activity with a button and an edittext. When you click the button the text in the edittext should end up as an item in a listview. Please help.

log:
http://i61.tinypic.com/14lq33n.jpg

Source:

```
package com.example.foodplannerbeta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Indkob2Activity extends Activity {

private Button bt;
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<String> al;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private EditText et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_indkob2);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncustomindkob);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customEdittrec);
    al = new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            al.add(et.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the logs. Or just look at them. That should tell you where the exception is coming from.

Comment: Can you post the exception trace?

Comment: Please read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this), and read it thoroughly. Everything you need to solve your problem is there.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace that you just posted, I believe the problem might be in the code you used to start your `Indkob2Activity`. Please post that code too.

Comment: Also please note sometimes Android Studio gets a little finicky about changes in string.xml and layout file names, so if you have made any changes of that sort recently, try changing them back, re-building, then adding the changes under different names and using them, re-building again, then removing the old code.

Comment: Which line of your activity corresponds to the exception in the stack trace? Also, don't post the stack trace as an image on another site. At least post the relevant line of the stack trace here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE seems to be on the `bt.setOnClickListener()` call. That is, `bt` is null.

Make sure your `activity_indkob2` layout in fact contains a view with id `btncustomindkob`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse you can see which line in the code is giving the error in the "LogCat"

In the log cat you should look for something like this-

```
at com.example.foodplannerbeta.Indkob2Activity.onCreate(Indkob2Activity.java:<ERROR LINE NUMBER>)
```